# VueJS: How to use Google places API with multiple refs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using the Google places API for my work and everything works fine. However, I have a unique scenario where I need to have more than one delivery address, hence I'll need to make Google place API works that way.

Here is my current code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(search, index) in searchInput" :key="index">
      <input type="text" ref="search" v-model="search.city">
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="addMore">Add more</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    location: null,
    searchInput: [
      {
        city: ""
      }
    ]
  }),
  mounted() {
    window.checkAndAttachMapScript(this.initLocationSearch);
  },
  methods: {
    initLocationSearch() {
      let autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        this.$refs.search
      );
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function() {
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place && place.address_components) {
          console.log(place.address_components);
        }
      });
    },
    addMore() {
      this.searchInput.push({ city: "" });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I get this error from the API: `InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement` and `b.ownerDocument is undefined`

How do I make the `refs` unique for the individual item that I add and then pass it to the `initLocationSearch` method? Please, any help would be appreciated.

Her is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dirac-f30un) demo

Answer (score 2):

Given the details you provided for the complete scenario, here is how I would do it.

I would use a simple counter to keep track of the number of inputs and set its initial value to `1` and also use it to display the inputs.

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in this.counter" :key="index">
  <input type="text" ref="search">
</div>
```

Then bind the Autocomplete widget to the last added input, based on the counter.

```
autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  this.$refs.search[this.counter - 1]
);
```

And use your `addMore()` method to increment the counter.

```
addMore() {
  this.counter++;
}
```

Use `updated()` for whenever a new input is added to the DOM to trigger the `initLocationSearch()` method.

```
updated() {
  this.initLocationSearch();
},
```

On `place_changed` event, update the list of selected cities based on the various input values.

```
this.selectedCities = this.$refs["search"].map(item => {
  return { city: item.value };
});
```

This way you always have an up to date list of cities, whatever input is changed. Of course you would need to handle emptying an input and probably other edge cases.

Complete code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(n, index) in this.counter" :key="index">
      <input type="text" ref="search">
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="addMore">Add more</button>
    <hr>Selected cities:
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in this.selectedCities" :key="index">{{ item.city }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    selectedCities: [],
    counter: 1
  }),
  mounted() {
    window.checkAndAttachMapScript(this.initLocationSearch);
  },
  updated() {
    this.initLocationSearch();
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedCities() {
      this.selectedCities = this.$refs["search"].map(item => {
        return { city: item.value };
      });
    },
    initLocationSearch() {
      let self = this,
        autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          this.$refs.search[this.counter - 1],
          {
            fields: ["address_components"] // Reduce API costs by specifying fields
          }
        );

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function() {
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place && place.address_components) {
          console.log(place);
          self.setSelectedCities();
        }
      });
    },
    addMore() {
      this.counter++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-fog-1efqy?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Okay. It works but not very well. I have to have an additional input before it works. For example, if the page loads, the first input doesn't work until I add another one, then the second doesn't work as well until I add a third input and so on.
https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-sea-n7obx

Comment: That's kind of a different question now. I wouldn't do it that way tbh. What's your goal with that code? Dynamically add many autocomplete fields and keep track of the selected cities in the `searchInput` array?

Comment: Exactly :) I want to be able to keep track of the result of each individual input and use them in an array as an array of object where each object is the individual input

Comment: @Peoray Did you ever get this working? I have a similar use case and I'm banging my head against the wall with the same type of off-by-one problem

Comment: Yes I did @ShaneOH, are you still having your issue?

Comment: Hey @Peoray thanks for responding! I actually got it to work too :) for any future readers, this question and answer helped lead me to the right place, and to solve the problem described in these comments, I basically started my "places" array as an array already containing 1 empty object, then my `place_changed` "set" the last value in my "places" array without pushing onto it. Then I had an "add address" button places.push() another empty placeholder object onto it, etc. -- I have some code here if it ends up helping anyone get on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75934616/4960410

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically bind to ref. Something like `:ref="'search' + index"`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(search, index) in searchInput" :key="index">
      <input type="text" :ref="'search' + index" v-model="search.city">
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="addMore">Add more</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in addMore, before creating a pushing on a new object to searchInput, grab the last index in searchInput. You can then get the newly created ref and pass that to `initLocationSearch`.

```
    initLocationSearch(inputRef) {
      let autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        inputRef
      );
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function() {
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place && place.address_components) {
          console.log(place.address_components);
        }
      });
    },
    addMore() {
      const lastInputRef = this.$refs['search' + this.searchInput.length - 1];
      this.initLocationSearch(lastInputRef);
      this.searchInput.push({ city: "" });
    }
```

Comment: The `index` is outside the scope. The button is not part of the loop. Getting index undefined error

Comment: Sorry, let me change my answer. I overlooked that. Let me have it how I had it before.