# Vue v-for always removing the last element, but setting key does not work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an app where I want to present the user with an initial input, which is a Maps autocomplete field. They input an address in there. Then, if they want, they can click the "+" sign to add more fields, and they can remove them if desired.

The template looks like this:

```
        <div class="address-inputs" v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
          <div>
            <label>Enter delivery point:</label>
          </div>
          <GMapAutocomplete @place_changed="setPlace" class="address-input" />
          <button class="btn" v-if="inputs.length > 1" @click="removeInput(index)">Remove</button>
          <div>
            <font-awesome-icon class="handle" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" @click="addInput" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

The data looks like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{lat: 0}], // dummy value to get the first input field to show up
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setPlace(place) {
      const input = {
        lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
      };

      this.inputs[this.inputs.length - 1] = input // replace the dummy value with a real address from autocomplete
    },
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({lat: 0}); // add another dummy value to get a new blank input field to show up
    },
    removeInput(index) {
      if (index < this.inputs.length) {
        this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
      }

      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    },
```

Basically, if I have `:key=index`, then removing works fine in terms of removing the correct address from `this.inputs`, but on the page it will always be the last address removed from the list of addresses.

It seems like you're supposed to use a unique identifier for `:key` instead, but when I try something like `:key="input.lat"` (for simplicity's sake, I know I can concat lat+lng etc.) then the address doesn't show up in the autocomplete field at all. It'll just appear for a second and then disappear.

Furthermore, I know my `setPlace` logic will break if, for example, the user adds 4 addresses and then goes to change the second one, instead of the assumed last one. But I also don't know how to get the index into that `setPlace` function.

Here is an example of the first address disappearing if I use an identifier as a key:

```
<div class="address-inputs" v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="`${input.lat}-${input.lng}`">
  <div>
    <label>Enter delivery point:</label>
  </div>
  <font-awesome-icon class="handle" icon="fa-solid fa-bars-staggered" />
  <GMapAutocomplete @place_changed="({ geometry: { location } }) => setPlace(location, index)" class="address-input" />
  <button class="btn" v-if="inputs.length > 1" @click="removeInput(index)">Remove</button>
<p>Here we have lat: {{input.lat}} lng: {{input.lng}} and index: {{index}}</p>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon class="handle" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" @click="addInput" />
  </div>
</div>
...
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{lat: 0, lng: 0}] // need a blank text GMapAutocomplete field to start
    };
  },
...
  methods: {
    // when this is called, this.inputs is updated properly, with the first address in the first slot at index 0 as expected, but the input disappears from the field instantly, instead of staying

    setPlace({ lat, lng }, index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1, {
        ...this.inputs[index],
        lat: lat(),
        lng: lng()
      })
    },
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({lat: 0, lng: 0}); // push the next blank text GMapAutocomplete field to the page for the user to enter in a new address
    },
    removeInput(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    },
```

The display only works if, in `setPlace()`, I `.push()` the new input instead of slicing it in-place, like `this.inputs.push({lat: lat(), lng: lng()})`. Then, the address will stay in the first field as expected. But then I have two problems:

1. The next input will automatically appear instead of only appearing when the user clicks the "+"
2. The actual input in the autocomplete seems to be "off by one" compared to the actual address values. I suspect this has something to do with the input disappearing if I try to slice it in place. See the below screenshot with the `<p>` debug statement I have in place:

[image: debug output]

Comment: send index to setPlace like this: `@place_changed="setPlace($event, index)"`.  and then a method declaration like `setPlace(place, index)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. Basically, if you want to be removing the proper entry in a list, you can't be using `index` as the v-for key, which was already established in the question. The problem was that I was trying to use the input `.lat` and `.lng` as my unique properties for the key instead. Normally this would work fine, expect that I was modifying that same property in my `setPlace()` function. So since I was actively modifying the same identifier I was keying on, it caused unexpected behavior in the list rendering.

The solution was simply to generate a random string as a unique `id` and then attach it to my inputs as `input.id` along with `input.lat` and `input.lng` and then use that as my v-for key instead. I didn't need to do anything special to keep track of the id either, simply assigning a unique string to it on every push was enough to get everything working!